# How to set attribute value in XML using JAVA

Tags: java, xml, attributes

i want to set an attribute value in the xml having xpath as: //Trade[@cancel] it doesn't matter what value is set before, but whatever value i sent that should get set

i am geting issue like No signature of method: org.apache.xml.dtm.ref.DTMNodeList.setAttribute() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values: [cancel, true] error at line: 26

even i don't want to pass existing value of attribute cancel: ("//Trade[@cancel='true']"
but i want to set some value to cancel. how to do it

```
enter code here

def file = """<DATA>
  <ASSET tid="4" AssetType="Loan">
    <Identifier tdes="FCSAstID" id="26415" />
    <Identifier tdes="CUSIP" id="13134MBN2" />
    <TRADEGROUP referenceticketid="YYasdfg"  />
    <TRADE LtdEventPubId="374104" Isname="true" cancel="false" value="30" positiontype="Assignment" quantity="50000.0000000000" >

    </TRADE>
</DATA>"""



Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
        .newDocumentBuilder().parse(file);

XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
NodeList  nodes = (NodeList)xpath.evaluate("//Trade[@cancel='true']",doc, 
XPathConstants.NODESET);

nodes.setAttribute("cancel","true")
```

Comment: Based on the HTML, there isn't an element matching the XPath `//Trade[@cancel='true']`. There *IS* an element matching XPath `//Trade[@cancel='false']`, however. I suspect this could be the issue

Comment: Please read the documentation. A [NodeList](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.xml/org/w3c/dom/NodeList.html) is - as the name suggests - a list of XML nodes. A NodeList doesn't have a method setAttribute(). This is the reason for the error message. You should extract the nodes out of the NodeList (method item()) and cast every Node to Element. [Element](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.xml/org/w3c/dom/Element.html) has a method setAttribute(String, String). Look at the documentation and search for tutorials if something is unclear.

Comment: @natn2323 that was a typo. It was not an issue.

Comment: @Vanje I am not good in java. Can you please provide me a solution/code that I can use to update //trade[@cancel] but I don't want to send the original value in it. And, while I am using a variable to pass the xpath then also it is not recognising.